# Xamarin obj-c binding when having other .h file referred in it

Tags: objective-c, xamarin, binding

I am confused when working with Xamarin obj-c bindings, Lets say if I am having a single .h file then its just an happy path when creating binding. But when a .h file is referenced with another .h in it as an import statement. How to deal with the bindings.

If I am having AB.h file which has A.h referred in it, what is the way to generate bindings for this. And If I am having a .xib file in obj-c project then how to deal with that.

Example Sake I am using this project for conversion.
https://github.com/hightower/HTHorizontalSelectionList/tree/master/Source

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Objective Sharpie](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/), it will automatically identify the dependency and help you get started with creating iOS bindings

Comment: Thank you prashant. I was using Objective sharpie through command line. But will try with GUI too.